# Presentation of $\mathbb{R}P^3$ in the Reshetikhin-Turaev Construction

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, mathematical-physics, knot-invariants

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RcIvzLvvFI&list=PL0a6GqRfGOz1q5f5ogPGpUNA-wNerDElp&index=12) at 1:02:00 the speaker gives a presentation for $\mathbb{R}P^3$ while discussing the Reshetikhin-Turaev Construction.  I'm struggling to figure out what that presentation has to do with $\mathbb{R}P^3$.  Any enlightenment you can provide is appreciated.